# How to write an if statement to check whether any item in array is greater than a specific value/date?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

So, I have a function which should be executed in case that a if condition is true. I simply do not know how to implement it in a method. I have the following code:

```
Meteor.methods({
 'popItems': function () {
   var date = new Date().getTime();

    if ( "check if this.userId && any item in the array 'itemIds' is $gt date" ) {

     userManagement.update({
      '_id': this.userId
     },  {
         $pop: {'itemIds': -1}
         }
        } 
      );
    };
  }
});
```

So, in case the if condition is true, the `$pop` function should be executed. In case false, it should not. I wrote this for the if clause, but it doesn't work:

```
if (this.userId && userManagement.find({
            'itemIds': {$gt: date}})) {...$pop function...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Meteor.methods({
    'popItems': function () {
        var date = new Date().getTime();

        if (this.userId && userManagement.find({'itemIds':{ $gt: date}}).count() > 0 ) {

            userManagement.update({
                '_id': this.userId
            },  {
                $pop: {'itemIds': -1}
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Many thanks! Implemented and works perfectly. I guess the .count > 0 tells the if, if there is more than 0 items which are $gt than date, do the $pop. That´s what I needed. I just couldn´t search out the syntax, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Include the query in the update operation as

```
Meteor.methods({
    'popItems': function () {
        var date = new Date();
        userManagement.update(
            {
                '_id': this.userId,
                'itemIds': { '$gt': date }
            },  
            { '$pop': { 'itemIds': -1 } }
        );
    }
});
```

I've made some assumptions in coming up with the above solution. The first one being `itemIds` is an array composed of just [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date) objects e.g.

```
itemIds: [
    ISODate("2017-01-25T06:20:00.000Z"),
    ISODate("2017-01-26T06:20:00.000Z"),
    ISODate("2017-01-27T06:20:00.000Z"),
    ...
    ISODate("2017-02-25T06:20:00.000Z")
]
```

---

The above query in the update operation can also be specified with an **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator as:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'popItems': function () {
        var date = new Date();
        userManagement.update(
            {
                '$and': [
                    { '_id': this.userId },
                    { 'itemIds': { '$gt': date } }, 
                ]
            },          
            { '$pop': { 'itemIds': -1 } }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Sounds very logic. However it $pop more than one item (exactly 2 items) out of the 'itemIds' array (don´t know why) when I use the $and version. I implemented the answer below with the if () and .count(), because this also workes fine and I just had to add the .count - thing. Would there be an advantage of your implementation?

Comment: The advantage is you do not need to make an extra call to the server with  `userManagement.find({'itemIds':{ $gt: date}}).count()`, all is done within the `update` function as part of the query object thus very efficient.